# Is it a good Idea to integrate IIS with Tomcat, or forget about it and stick to Apache HTTP with Tomcat

Tags: apache, http, iis, tomcat

Do you think it is possible to achieve the same performance found in **["Apache Http"-"Tomcat"]** with **["IIS"-"Tomcat"]** ?

Just want to know what you think about the IIS-Tomcat combo (Performance-wise)

Comment: Isn't tomcat a standalone server?  When I used to work with it, I'm pretty sure we didn't use Apache (and definitely not IIS).  It has been like 4 years since I did that though.

Comment: Yes, Tomcat is a container that can be accessed directly but best used when integrated with Apache that takes care of serving static pages, security, etc.

Comment: Tomcat is a Servlet container. Apache Http is a webserver.
Tomcat is not as fast as Apache when it comes to static pages.
Tomcat is not as configurable as Apache.
Tomcat is not as robust as Apache.
Tomcat may not address many sites' need for functionality found only in Apache modules (eg Perl, PHP).

Comment: Yes, Tomcat is a standalone server.

Comment: Wouldn't Apache Tomcat and Apache Webserver be a better combo than Apache Tomcat and Microsoft IIS. I'm sure you can have IIS as a webserver frontend for Tomcat but, what's the point?

Comment: Some people try to realize the benefits (ease of use, familiarity with Windows environment, maintenance of IIS on windows environment) of IIS found in windows O.S. and at the same time use JSPs, Servelets etc. The IIS-Tomcat is not uncommon but also no abundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done but it is not a great idea. An array of integration problems can be avoided by simply using the well known combo ["Apache Http"-"Tomcat"].